# Exporting threeJS scene to STL file results to very big file size

Tags: javascript, three.js, filesize, exporter

I want to export my threeJS scene to STL file. 
I am using this exporter : https://gist.github.com/kjlubick/fb6ba9c51df63ba0951f

My problem is the file size that I get. For example, for 4 spheres (created via  `new THREE.SphereGeometry(1,32, 32)`  ) I got a file of 15MB, which I think is huge if you think that this ball here : http://archive3d.net/?a=download&id=469e26a6 is less than 0.5 MB.

Is there any way to reduce the file size? Why is it so big for just 4 spheres?
One way is to create some low res (`new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 16, 16)`) temp spheres at the time of exporting and delete them afterwards, but is there any other better way?

**EDIT : I had done a mistake independently from the exporting process, and when I corrected it the size went down to 6 MB but it is still very big for just 2 spheres.**

Thank you in advance, any opinion will be appreciated.

Comment: It's the nature of textual 3D formats. If you have a lot of triangles, the file will be big. Maybe you can try binary stl: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29#Binary_STL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exported you have linked uses the [ASCII STL format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)), which by its nature is quite verbose and takes up a significant number of bytes to store a single triangle. Each of your spheres would be composed of several thousand triangles. Options are to:

- Use the binary STL file format. This is a much more compact representation, using 50 bytes per facet. According to some back of the envelope calculations*, this would take ~0.1MB per sphere. The three.js repository has a [binary STL exporter example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/exporters/STLBinaryExporter.js).
- Reduce the numeric precision you use to export your numbers. If you export numbers like `0.1` rather than `0.100001` it will take less characters to hold your result (but you will lose precision).
- Use less triangles to make up your spheres as discussed in the question.
- If you are *really really* desperate to use ASCII you could also try removing some of the unneccesary whitespace indentation the exporter generates, but this would yield only very minor improvements.

<sub>* Assuming 32 * 32 * 2 triangles per sphere, 32 * 32 * 2 * 50 = ~100e3 = ~0.1MB</sub>

Comment: thanks for your answer.
1. Binary stl is a great idea but there is not any binary exporter out there but I am struggling right now to develop one on my own. Have I missed any js stl bin. exporter?

2. I tried your idea but it gave me little results as far as size is concerned

Comment: 3. I did that and it really helped!

Comment: 4. I am not desperate to use ascii, I just don't have yet a binary exporter.

Comment: @ThanosKw I found one in the official three.js repository, I will edit my answer to include it.